# Does 次の always indicate a temporal relationship?

Tags: meaning

> 今年はほかに、片渕須直監督の「この世界の片隅に」が、**クリスタル賞の次の賞**の「審査員賞」をもらいました。
>   Additionally, this year, director 片渕須直's 'In the Corner of this World' received the Judges Prize, which is ???

Does クリスタル賞の次の賞 mean the prize which is awarded after the Crystal prize, or the prize which is second best to the Crystal prize?

When I first read the sentence I thought it meant the second best prize, but then I started to worry that 次 might only describe a temporal relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with you; it's theoretically ambiguous, but I also read this as the second best prize after Crystal Prize.

For example one can say:

> - 富士山の次に高い日本の山は何ですか？
>     What's the next highest mountain in Japan after Mt. Fuji?
> - 次に安いのを見せてください。
>     Let me see the next cheapest one.

Comment: 英語だと "What is the Japanese mountain which is the next highest to Mt. Fuji?" でいいんでしょうか（自信がない）

Comment: in English, that sounds more like there is a mountain taller than Fuji. i think in English it'd be better to say, "after mt Fuji, which is the next highest mountain?".   but even that sounds clunky to me.

Comment: @naruto - Yes, that's perfectly fine. It reads a little formally, as though it might be, say, a question in a geography exam. A more colloquial version might be "What's the next highest mountain in Japan after Mt Fuji?" Regards.

Comment: @A.Ellett I think I don't read it that way because if that were the question rather than using の after 富士山 I'd expect より instead. That being said, I've always read 次 as "next", in a way. So, going by ordinance, I'd contextually expect the tallest first then second tallest next